# find repeated list of words with php

Tags: php, text

This is an easy question, still I don't how how to figure it out.

I have a list of words like:

```
word
word
    one
    two
    three
    four
    five
    .
    ....X100
word
word
```

with the words (one, two, three, four, five) repeated exactly, and in the same order, let's say 100 times. the words (word) are not repeated and should be ignored.

I want to get that list of (one, two, three , four, five) with exactly the same order. How can this be done in php.
All I tried until now can just count number of occurrences of words, and don't respect the word order.

**Update**

Thank you for you answers everyone!

here is my code, still has a lot of errors

```
<?php
$str = 'word
word
word2
word3
one
two
three
four
one
two
three
four
one
two
three
four
one
two
three
four
one
two
three
four
one
two
three
four
yes
no 
do';
function repeated($str)
{
    $str=trim($str);  
    $str=ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', ' ',$str);  
    $words=explode(' ',$str);  
    $lastWord = '';
    foreach($words as $w)  
    {  
        $wordstats[($w)]++;  

        if($lastWord!=''){
            $wordstats[$lastWord.' '.$w]++;
        }
        $lastWord = $w;
    }  
    foreach($wordstats as $k=>$v)  
    {  
        if($v>=2)  
        {  
            print "$k"." , ";  
        }  
    }  
}

print repeated($str);

?>
```

basically what I want is to give php that $str text, which will have the words (one,two,three,four) repeated many times inside of it, and determine the pattern (one,two,three,four) that's all

Comment: Is this a text file that you are trying to parse?  Will there always be a tab or several spaces at the beginning of the lines you are interested in?

Comment: Please explain your question better

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If show how you did the word count we can amend it to do ordering too.

Comment: @Mike No there will no tags or spaces at the beginning. here is a sample text in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Now, please consider this as a hint:

You could use a counting variable and an Array.
Create an array of those words you want:

```
$SearchMe = array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
$Index = 0;
```

Next, iterate through that list you want.
But don't check for 'One', 'Two', 'Three', but rather for:

```
$SearchMe[$Index];
```

Each time, you FIND $SearchMe[$Index], iterate it by one, until you're at the end of the array. Once you're there, you increment another counter, for you have found your sequence.
At the end of the sequence, or if you find a mismatch, remember to reset $Index to 0.

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

**update**
I think this isn't the answer you are looking for. After reading your question again I am not quite sure what you are actually asking. So please provide us with more information so we can be more accurate.

--

I think you are looking for something like this. Is your list an array? If so:

```
    <?php      
    foreach ($list as $key => $value ){
      if (isarray($value)){
        $ListINeed[] = $value;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

When you have the array you posted in your opening post, this will return:

```
    $ListINeed[1] = array(
      [0] => one
      [1] => two
      [2] => three
      [3] => four
      [4] => five
      [x] => .
      [100] => ....X100
    )
```

If you are sure that the ListINeed will only be there once, delete the two brackets ([]) after the $ListINeed in the first piece of code in the if-statement. Then you will get

```
    $ListINeed = array(
      [0] => one
      [1] => two
      [2] => three
      [3] => four
      [4] => five
      [x] => .
      [100] => ....X100
    )
```